# xamarin ios 16.0 system.argumentexception: 'nan is not a valid value for width' n main.cs;

Tags: ios, xamarin

Xamarin.Forms-NaN-is-not-a-valid-value-for-width

Visual Studio 2022 (17.3.6)

Xamarin 17.3.0.308
in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.0.0.75 (e4f48bed7)

the problem when i tab on page the application abort and close
this exception occur in ios 16.0

```
public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");//here is the exception occur
        }
    }
```

xaml.cs

```
<ListView  x:Name="AbyatListView" 
                               BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}" 
                               HasUnevenRows="True" HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell >

                                    <Grid  Padding="5,5,5,5">

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding text1}" FontFamily="{Binding fonttext}" FontSize="20" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextSecondaryColor}" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding text2}" FontFamily="{Binding fonttext}" FontSize="20" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextSecondaryColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

> log

```
**System.ArgumentException:** 'NaN is not a valid value for width'

2022-11-04 20:31:20.181167+0200 MotonQasida.iOS[3631:26150] 
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: NaN is not a valid value for width
  at Xamarin.Forms.Size..ctor (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Size.cs:20 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.UIViewExtensions.GetSizeRequest (UIKit.UIView self, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, System.Double minimumWidth, System.Double minimumHeight) [0x00010] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Extensions\UIViewExtensions.cs:91 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].GetDesiredSize (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:148 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.LabelRenderer.GetDesiredSize (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\LabelRenderer.cs:56 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platf
orm.GetNativeSize (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00040] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:220 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Forms+IOSPlatformServices.GetNativeSize (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Forms.cs:760 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00025] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:876 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:861 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:750 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint
, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:802 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid+GridStructure.MeasuredStarredColumns (Xamarin.Forms.Grid grid, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, System.Double totalStarsWidth) [0x000da] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:670 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid+GridStructure.MeasureAndContractStarredColumns (Xamarin.Forms.Grid grid, System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Double totalStarsWidth) [0x0000e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:588 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid+GridStructure..ctor (Xamarin.Forms.Grid grid, System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Boolean requestSize) [0x000ee] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:136 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x0002a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:55 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightCons
traint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:861 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:750 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:802 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+UnevenListViewDataSource.CalculateHeightForCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell) [0x0004d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:963 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+UnevenListViewDataSource.GetEstimatedRowHeight (UIKit.UITableView table) [0x00097] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderer
s\ListViewRenderer.cs:884 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+UnevenListViewDataSource.UpdateEstimatedRowHeight (UIKit.UITableView tableView) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:899 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.DetermineEstimatedRowHeight () [0x00009] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:1351 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsUITableViewController.ViewWillLayoutSubviews () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:1694 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.xamarin_UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (System.Int32 argc, System.String[] argv, System.IntPtr principalClassName, System.IntPtr delegateClassName) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.0.0.75/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:57 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[]
 args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00013] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.0.0.75/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:82 
  at MotonQasida.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\Samer Alqadi\Documents\MEGAsync\MotonQasida\MotonQasida\MotonQasida.iOS\Main.cs:18
2022-11-04 20:31:20.185139+0200 MotonQasida.iOS[3631:26150] Unhandled managed exception: NaN is not a valid value for width (System.ArgumentException)
  at Xamarin.Forms.Size..ctor (System.Double width, System.Double height) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Size.cs:20 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.UIViewExtensions.GetSizeRequest (UIKit.UIView self, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, System.Double minimumWidth, System.Double minimumHeight) [0x00010] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Extensions\UIViewExtensions.cs:91 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].GetDesiredSize (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:148 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.LabelRenderer.GetDesiredSize (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00008] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\LabelRenderer.cs:56 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.i
OS.Platform.GetNativeSize (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00040] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:220 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Forms+IOSPlatformServices.GetNativeSize (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Forms.cs:760 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00025] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:876 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:861 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:750 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightCo
nstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:802 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid+GridStructure.MeasuredStarredColumns (Xamarin.Forms.Grid grid, System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, System.Double totalStarsWidth) [0x000da] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:670 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid+GridStructure.MeasureAndContractStarredColumns (Xamarin.Forms.Grid grid, System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Double totalStarsWidth) [0x0000e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:588 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid+GridStructure..ctor (Xamarin.Forms.Grid grid, System.Double width, System.Double height, System.Boolean requestSize) [0x000ee] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:136 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x0002a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridCalc.cs:55 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double he
ightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:861 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00053] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:750 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:802 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+UnevenListViewDataSource.CalculateHeightForCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Xamarin.Forms.Cell cell) [0x0004d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:963 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+UnevenListViewDataSource.GetEstimatedRowHeight (UIKit.UITableView table) [0x00097] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\
Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:884 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+UnevenListViewDataSource.UpdateEstimatedRowHeight (UIKit.UITableView tableView) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:899 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.DetermineEstimatedRowHeight () [0x00009] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:1351 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsUITableViewController.ViewWillLayoutSubviews () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:1694 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.xamarin_UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (System.Int32 argc, System.String[] argv, System.IntPtr principalClassName, System.IntPtr delegateClassName) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.0.0.75/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:57 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.
String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00013] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.0.0.75/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:82 
  at MotonQasida.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\Samer Alqadi\Documents\MEGAsync\MotonQasida\MotonQasida\MotonQasida.iOS\Main.cs:18
```

args length is zero !

i try to update
visual studio to 2022
and xcode 14
and latest version of xamarin form
and xamarin ios

Comment: The exception is shown at that line because your app UI has died; that is the only line still on the stack. It isn't where the exception actually happened. Iisolate what on the "page" you mention causes the problem when you "tab": **Add to question the code that runs when user "tabs"**.  There is some method called in your code? Wrap method contents in `try .. catch`, and put a breakpoint inside `catch`. You should see that exception message there now. Your app should no longer crash, though tab doesn't work. Now remove code and xaml until you find what causes problem.

Comment: I don't see any problem in xaml you show. Unclear why xamarin can't measure width for Label. To isolate the problem, here are some tests: **1)** Remove 2nd label (to make xaml simpler for testing). Change 1st label to: `<Label Grid.Row="0" Text="TEST" />` Just that; don't have `FontFamily`, etc. Work? **2)** If that did not work, then also add `WidthRequest` to `ListView`: `<ListView  x:Name="AbyatListView" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor=...>`. DO keep all your current properties. Work?

Comment: I tried to use the same xaml layout as yours, using `Binding` and `Text="Test"` in the Label is displayed normally. Could you provide more code about your use of Binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by update nuget packages

**update Xamarin.Forms => 5.0.0.2545**

**update Xamarin.Essentials => 1.7.4**